# External monitor has wrong resolution

Tags: display

I have a 23' external monitor (through VGA) which always worked at 1440x900 and looked amazing. Today after I unplugged it, it still says it's working at 1440x900 but it's actual resolution is bigger.

I've tried unplugging, rebooting, Detect Displays, change res. and change back but no dice. Any clues on what might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume by bigger, you mean smaller, in that the UI elements are larger thus indicating a lower resolution?  Any idea what the resolution is?  Is the aspect ratio correct?

Comment: Yeah, I mean smaller :D Actually the resolution was 1920x1080. I remeber now that I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) and see what happens.